# Explanation of android calculator code

Tags: java, android, calculator

I was creating a simple calculator with android. I searched the google and found this fragment of code which worked perfectly for me. But I cannot understand this fragment of the code which was implemented on the onCreate() method. Can someone please explain me this part of code?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

          Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
          int[]Btn_Id={ R.id.Btn0, R.id.Btn1, R.id.Btn2, R.id.Btn3,R.id.Btn4, R.id.Btn5, R.id.Btn6, R.id.Btn7, R.id.Btn8, R.id.Btn9, R.id.BtnClear, R.id.BtnDecimal, R.id.BtnDivide, R.id.BtnMultiply, R.id.BtnSubtract, R.id.BtnAdd, R.id.BtnEqual }; 

           for(int i: Btn_Id) { 
               ((Button)findViewById(i)).setOnClickListener(this); 
            } 
       }
```

Comment: May be it is creating button programatically.. so in this code all button's ids are given programaticaly.. also set onclick listner with for loop as all buttons needs a listner so implemeted in the loop

Comment: share on create snippet

Comment: @MadhuNair
`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 int[]Btn_Id={ R.id.Btn0, R.id.Btn1, R.id.Btn2, R.id.Btn3, R.id.Btn4, R.id.Btn5, R.id.Btn6, R.id.Btn7, R.id.Btn8, R.id.Btn9, R.id.BtnClear, R.id.BtnDecimal, R.id.BtnDivide, R.id.BtnMultiply, R.id.BtnSubtract, R.id.BtnAdd, R.id.BtnEqual
 };
 for(int i: Btn_Id) {
      ((Button)findViewById(i)).setOnClickListener(this);
 }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **int[]Btn_Id**

it is a array of button which contain id of buttons  defined in layout resource file

> The below code is used to set `ClickListener` to all `Button`  in your `Btn_Id` array

```
for(int i: Btn_Id) {
     ((Button)findViewById(i)).setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `onCreate` is called when activity starts, its the entry point for the activity.

And activity is empty window, the `setContentView` is used to fill the resource of id `R.layout.activity_main`

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);, you tell the Dalvik VM to run your code in addition to the existing code in the onCreate() of the parent class. If you leave out this line, then only your code is run. The existing code is ignored completely.

`R.id.Btn0....` means its defined in resource file and used to show 0 and other buttons. `int[]Btn_Id` variable holds the resource id of the used buttons.

The following line assigns listener for button click for all the buttons:

```
for(int i: Btn_Id) {
    ((Button)findViewById(i)).setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hear is the solution of your problem hope you understand code till

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

which will create toast message 'welcome' when activity launch.

```
int[]Btn_Id={ R.id.Btn0, R.id.Btn1, R.id.Btn2, R.id.Btn3,R.id.Btn4, R.id.Btn5, R.id.Btn6, R.id.Btn7, R.id.Btn8, R.id.Btn9, R.id.BtnClear, R.id.BtnDecimal, R.id.BtnDivide, R.id.BtnMultiply, R.id.BtnSubtract, R.id.BtnAdd, R.id.BtnEqual };
```

Above the Btn_Id is an integer array that will store ID of the all button from btn0 to btnEqual

```
for(int i: Btn_Id) { 
           ((Button)findViewById(i)).setOnClickListener(this); 
        }
```

this function called for each loop. It work like for every int ID in array Btn_Id and assign to int i. and for every i set Button.setOnClickListner(this)\ this is a context.

if you try to find a source code of android calculator then you can get from hear free.

Download Source code:https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdMmtAIsH0KYiKrdpbzat6t96Nb1_k3_1